# Firefox - how to manually disable internet connection for a single loaded tab

Tags: networking, firefox

Is there a way in Firefox to manually disable the Internet connection for a loaded tab?

I need to open a tab, load the website in it, then make sure the tab can't use the Internet connection anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [throttle](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/throttling/index.html) the tab's connection to `Offline`.

To do so, open the dev tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), go to the `Network` tab, and in the top-right change `No Throttling` to `Offline`. This will implicitly block all requests made by the tab.

Comment: Thanks, it works and it is simple. It should be better with a easy to use toggle button as addon in the topbar, but your solution is enought for now

Answer (score 2):

Updated: This applies to the whole browser (below steps) and currently, there is no other way.

This is not so difficult. You just have to use the **developer tools**.

**Steps:**

1. Click the Browser Settings button in the upper right-hand corner.

[image]

2. Click **Web Developer**.
3. Click **Work Offline**.

Unfortunately, it does not look like has an option to make a single tab go offline like in **Chrome Dev tools**. Dev tools in Chrome provides this option for a specific tab (Network > Offline).

Firefox may come up with this option during their development lifecycle. There were some ongoing requests and discussions [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1156659).

Comment: It isn't what I need. It enables "work offline" for all tabs, not only for the desired tab.

Comment: Yep, my apologies. Looks like it applies to the whole browser. I thought it might work as in Chrome but unfortunately not. You could use Google Chrome and it's dev tools (Network option). It provides a per-tab based offline option. Looks like Firefox has no way yet. Please see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1156659

Comment: When I enable offline mode it affects web page loading but my ajax connections are still going through lol

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Request Blocking" feature to block future requests from a single tab.

From the Network pane in the Developer Tools console, enable Request Blocking, then add a `*` matching rule to cover all URLs.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824319.